# How replace "-" only in a *text* value of any generic jsonb in postgresql?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-10

I need to clean JSON data that could look like:

```
{
   "reference":"0000010-CAJ",
   "product_code":"00000-10",
   "var_name":"CAJ-1",
   "doc_date":"2020-02-09T21:01:01-05:00",
   "due_date":"2020-03-10T21:01:01-05:00",
}
```

However, this is just one of many other possibilities (is for a log aggregation that gets data from many sources).

I need to replace "-" with "_", but without break the dates like "2020-03-10T21:01:01-05:00", so can't simply cast to string and do a replace. I wonder if exist an equivalent of:

```
for (k,v) in json:
   if is_text(v):
       v = replace(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with a regex if the value looks like a timestamp:

```
update the_table 
  set the_column = (select 
                     jsonb_object_agg(
                         key, 
                         case 
                            when value ~ '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*' then value
                           else replace(value, '-', '_')
                         end)
                    from jsonb_each_text(the_column) as t(key, value))
```

This iterates over all key/value pairs in the JSON column (using `jsonb_each_text()`) and assembles all of them back into a JSON again (using jsonb_object_agg()). Values that look like a timestamp are left unchanged, for all others, the `-` is replaced with a `_`.

Comment: This help to filter dates, but not to select only the text values...

Comment: @mamcx: sorry, then I don't know what exactly you want.